Acrobat.exe process doesn't terminate when closing file tab from acrobat .net core
I'm having a problem with closing my application. I'm using .net core c# to open a PDF file in Acrobat. After I'm done I close Acrobat and I am able to close my application as we are terminating process on Exit.
But when I close file tab from Acrobat in this case my application is still running in the background and not getting closed in file tab close.
Alternatively I have to kill the all the pdf acrobat process  which I do not want.
I want to get an event based on file tab close.
var process = Process.start(new ProcessStartInfo
 {
    FileName = deafaultReader,
    Arguments = $"/n {filepath}",
    UseShellExecute = true
 }
 );

process.EnableRaiseingEvent = true;
process.Exited = true;  // this is listening adobe acrobat close event 
return process;
// here we are able to close our desktop application when we close adobe acrobat  but we close opened pdf file tab in this case application  still running in background.`


Process class does not know anything about Tabs in Acrobat. So you can't get an event of that interna or you find something explicitly mentioned in the acrobats documentation. But i would doubt that you even listening to the correct process here at all times. Typically these Tab bases UIs work by, when being started again, to call an already running process of its own opening a tab there and then ending itself. So you might have opened the process to show a file but its not the process you listening here to and waiting for its exit.

Forget parts about what i wrote missed that you used the /n parameter in your code.
